# Dynamic and growing list of topics in a cell for analysis

Tags: google-sheets, list

My issue is that I am building a workbook (see minimum viable example attached) that identifies multiple topics that occur in each section of a book chapter for multiple book chapters. This workbook will require the users to be able to see a growing list of multiple topics (i.e., categorical data) as an index somehow as they're inputting the data.

Each row is a distinct section of a chapter (e.g., 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2...), and the primary column (or columns) is a list of topics. There will also be columns with information on each chapter section (e.g., title). See my sample below:

[image]

And I want to be able to automatically generate a continuously added list like this:

[image]

For excel, I was provided with an example formula solution that doesn't have sheets compatibility:

> =LET(t,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",,Sheet1!C2:C5),",")))),t)

Thank you!

-Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> =unique(transpose(split(join(",",C2:C),",")))

Let me know ;)

Comment: Hello @doubleunary, yes, by default they're TRUE, that's why I didn't specify them

Comment: Thanks for this solution, there is a small issue with it in that it logs before and after commas different on the list. For example, "cookies, bread" would log "cookies" as an item, and then "bread, cookies" would log " cookies" as a separate item. Looks like =ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",1,Sheet1!C2:C5),","))))) as suggested solves that problem.